# how to get the text of collectionViewCell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing problem to get the text of collectionViewCell.
when I select a particular cell.
I am using various code but no one is useful for me. 
So, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Add some code. So others can identify where is problem.

Comment: specify exactly what you want add some code to understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your going to have to create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class...

A simple way to utilize a `UICollectionView` is creating a Calendar Month View with multiple `UICollectionViewCells` as the distinct days within a month view.

Heres the basic implementation of the `UICollectionViewCell` i used with a `UICollectionView`:

```
CBCalendarCell.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CBCalendarCell : UICollectionViewCell    
@property UIView *circleView;    
@property UIView *selectedView;    
@property UILabel *dateLabel;
@property UIView *eventView;    
@end



CBCalendarCell.m

#import "CBCalendarCell.h"
#import "CBConstants.h"

@implementation CBCalendarCell
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) return nil;

    self.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;

    self.dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height * labelToCellRatio)];
    self.dateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    self.eventView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.dateLabel.frame.size.width / 2.0f - 1.5f,
                                                              self.dateLabel.frame.origin.y + self.dateLabel.frame.size.height - 5,
                                                              3, 3)];
    [[self.eventView layer] setCornerRadius:1.5f];
    [self.eventView setBackgroundColor:cellEventViewColor];

    CGRect labelFrame = self.dateLabel.frame;
    CGSize labelSize = labelFrame.size;

    CGPoint origin;
    int length;
    if (labelSize.width > labelSize.height) {
        origin.x = (labelSize.width - labelSize.height * circleToCellRatio) / 2;
        origin.y = (labelSize.height * (1 - circleToCellRatio)) / 2;
        length = labelSize.height * circleToCellRatio;
    }
    else{
        origin.x = (labelSize.width * (1 - circleToCellRatio)) / 2;
        origin.y = (labelSize.height - labelSize.width * circleToCellRatio) / 2;
        length = labelSize.width * circleToCellRatio;
    }

    self.circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, length, length)];

    self.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = length / 2;
    self.circleView.backgroundColor = currentDateCircleColor;

    self.selectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, length, length)];

    self.selectedView.layer.cornerRadius = length / 2;
    self.selectedView.backgroundColor = selectedDateCircleColor;

    [self.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:self.circleView];
    [self.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:self.selectedView];
    [self.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:self.dateLabel];
    [self.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:self.eventView];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Register the custom UICollectionViewCell within the UICollectionView like so:

```
// 'calendar' is the UICollectionView instance name
[calendar registerClass:[CBCalendarCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

Then in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` configure the cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CBCalendarCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
    ...
    cell.circleView.hidden = YES;
    cell.selectedView.hidden = NO;
    cell.dateLabel.text = @"Text";
    cell.eventView.hidden = NO;
    ...
    ...
    return cell;
}
```

This code was pulled from SACalendar repository... All rights reserved to Nop Shusang

Comment: What is  { viewForBaselineLayout } in this code ?

Comment: viewForBaselineLayout is the view of the UICollectionViewCell that satisfies the baseline constraints of the view https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewForBaselineLayout

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a default `UICollectionView` class then you may use this line of code.

```
UICollectionView *cell //use alloc etc

cell.textLabel.text //this line return the text of collectionviewcell. as in UITableView
```

Comment: 'cell.yourLabel.text'

Comment: @jsetting32, how we can show code like the one you edited..

Comment: I used this code but cell.textlabel.text is not supported by CollectionViewCell . It's giving an error.

Comment: When writing a post, there's a button {}. Select the text you want to display as 'code' formatted, press the button and wallah

Comment: @AngelSharma what ever the outlet of your label in UICollectionView is